# How can I change values of data with condition in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure how to explain my problem.. But I have a series that looks like this:

```
0 Male 
1 Female                   
2 male                                       
3 M                                        
4 m                                  
5 LGBT                                   
6 Others                           
7 Make                          
8 Male                              
9 Man                                
10 Cis Male
```

And I'm trying to narrow it down to:

```
Male
Female
Others
LGBT
```

I was able to narrow it down using:

```
LGBT = survey['Gender'].str.contains('Trans|Neuter|queer|andro|Andro|Enby|binary|trans')
survey.loc[LGBT, 'Gender'] = 'LGBT'

Others = survey['Gender'].str.contains('N|A|p')
survey.loc[Others, 'Gender'] = 'Others'

Female = survey['Gender'].str.contains('F|Wo|f|wo')
survey.loc[Female, 'Gender'] = 'Female'
```

For each section, but now I'm trying to have the rest of the items into 'Male', I'm not able to do so. I tried using Regex but because 'Female' also contains 'm', it just changes everything to Male...

How can I solve this problem? What kind of function should I look into? I tried `eq` such as below:

```
survey['Gender'].eq(['Male', 'Female', 'Others', 'LGBT']).map({False: 'Male'})
```

But it gave me an error of:

```
ValueError: Lengths must be equal
```

And I'm getting more confused.... Any advice and help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.isin`, which is useful when you want to compare multiple values at the same time.

```
Male = ~survey['Gender'].isin(['Female', 'Others', 'LGBT'])
survey.loc[Male, 'Gender'] = 'Male'
```

Since you have already narrowed down the other cases, you can just check if the elements are equal to any of the previously set (`Female`, `Others`, `LGBT`) and, if not, you set them as `Male`.